# flickering doing setState using nested api calls in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to load a bunch of data that involves multiple APIs, I did setState in foreach, it worked but I think the design is wrong, as I see flickering on my screen.

```
API.fetchMain().then(main => {
  main.forEach(o => {
    const main_id = o.main_id

    this.setState({
      main: o
    })

      API.fetchSub(main_id)
      .then(sub => {

        this.setState({
          sub
        })

        API.fetchOthers(main_id, sub.id)
        .then(others => {
          this.setState({
            others
          })
        })

      })
  })
}
```

I think I should use promises to refactor, I tried but I think my design was wrong.

```
API.fetchMain().then(main => {

  let promise = []

  main.forEach(o => {
    const main_id = o.main_id

    this.setState({
      main: o
    })

    promise.push(
      API.fetchSub(main_id)
      .then(sub => {

        return API.fetchOthers(main_id, sub.id)

      })
    )
  })

  Promise.all(promise).then(resp => console.log('do setState here'))

}
```

Need help.

Comment: Uh, you're calling `setState` in a loop with different values. Of course it would flicker.

Comment: @Bergi will using promise fix that? if I can wait all of them resolve then setState once for different piece of arrays I think it will be ok.

Comment: Well I still don't know what you actually want this to do, but probably your state will need to contain multiple values that are individually set.

Comment: @Bergi I want to collect data from multiple source, then setState once in the end. I can setState in the middle of every calls, but caused rerender for few times which is not good.

Comment: And how do you want to represent the collected data? Currently every iteration is writing to the same `state.main` property.

Comment: @Bergi I think my logic is wrong, I need to collect each piece in each loop, now newer loop is replacing the old data.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to tell you :-) Collect them, and then do *what* with the multiple pieces? You first need to figure out what you want to do and explain it to use, then I can help you with the promises.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are fetching a resource that provides you with information about how to make further requests. If you are open to using a fetch library I would recommend [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). Heres how I would envision it looking

```
import axios from 'axios'

fetch(){
  // Make the initial request
  var options = { url: "URL of main resource", method: "GET" }
  axios(options).then(res => {
    // Create an array of next requests from the response
    var next_requests = res.data.main.map(id => axios.get(`${resource_url}/${id}`))

    //Make the requests in parallel
    axios.all(next_requests).then(axios.spread(() => {
       //since we don't know how many request we can iterate 
       //over the arguments object and build the new state
       var newState = {}
       arguments.forEach(i => {
         // how you want to structure the the state before setting it
       })
       this.setState(newState)    
    })

  }).catch(err => //error handling logic here)
}
```

From my understanding of your question you could also (since you are using react) break your fetch request into components that get called when they mount. A quick example:

```
const class MainComp extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      main: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){ this.fetchMain() }

  fetchMain() { 
     axios.get('url').then(res => 
        this.setState({main_id: res.data.main.id})
  }

  sendSubFetchToParent(dataFromChild){
     // Do what you need to with the data from the SubComp child
  }

  render(){
     return (
        {this.state.main.map(id => <SubComp id={id) afterFetch={this.sendSubFetchToParent}/>}
     )
  }
}

const class SubComp extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){ this.fetchSub() }

  fetchSub() { 
     //Pass the results to the parent after the fetch completes.
     // You can add the usual error handling here as well.
     axios.get('url').then(res => this.props.afterFetch(res.data))
  }

  render(){
     //Return null or render another sub component for further nested requests
     return null
  }
}
```

In the above, MainComp initiates a request. When it gets a response (which in your example is an array) we set that response to the state. This triggers rerender which will mount n number of SubComp. When those mount they will initiate their requests to get data. For SubComp we pass a callback from the parent so SubComp can send its fetch response back to MainComp (And handle it appropriately by setting state etc etc). You can return null in SubComp or have it mount a component that will make further request.

In that way your fetch requests are now componentized.